# getting problem in android listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

i am trying folling code into android

```
tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ringtone);
    if (!hasErrors) {

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindFilesByType.this, R.layout.main,
                Ringtones));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> aView, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                currentPosition = position;
                playRingtone(DIRECTORY+Ringtones.get(position));
            }
        });
```

but i am getting following Logcat and my application close forcefully close

```
04-27 11:05:08.212: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=android.com.testHTML/.FindFilesByType }
04-27 11:05:08.353: INFO/NotificationService(52): enqueueToast pkg=android.com.testHTML callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@4394f760 duration=0
04-27 11:05:08.454: ERROR/ArrayAdapter(715): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
04-27 11:05:08.454: WARN/dalvikvm(715): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
04-27 11:05:08.454: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1273)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1658)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:694)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1516)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1112)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6569)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1108)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:920)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6569)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6569)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6569)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6569)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:979)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1613)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340)
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     ... 30 more
04-27 11:05:08.493: INFO/Process(52): Sending signal. PID: 715 SIG: 3
04-27 11:05:08.493: INFO/dalvikvm(715): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-27 11:05:08.503: ERROR/dalvikvm(715): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
04-27 11:05:13.472: INFO/Process(715): Sending signal. PID: 715 SIG: 9
04-27 11:05:13.503: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Process android.com.testHTML (pid 715) has died.
04-27 11:05:13.512: INFO/WindowManager(52): WIN DEATH: Window{43885018 android.com.testHTML/android.com.testHTML.testHTMLActivity paused=false}
04-27 11:05:13.512: INFO/WindowManager(52): WIN DEATH: Window{43933640 Toast paused=false}
04-27 11:05:13.512: INFO/WindowManager(52): WIN DEATH: Window{439071b0 android.com.testHTML/android.com.testHTML.FindFilesByType paused=false}
04-27 11:05:13.592: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Start proc android.com.testHTML for activity android.com.testHTML/.testHTMLActivity: pid=750 uid=10024 gids={3003, 1015}
04-27 11:05:13.784: INFO/jdwp(750): received file descriptor 20 from ADB
04-27 11:05:13.913: WARN/UsageStats(52): Something wrong here, didn't expect android.com.testHTML to be resumed
04-27 11:05:14.503: WARN/InputManagerService(52): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 715 uid 10024
04-27 11:05:14.643: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Displayed activity android.com.testHTML/.testHTMLActivity: 1139 ms (total 6398 ms)
```

what is wrong i am doing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your layout XML? Are you sure that `R.id.ringtone` refers to the TextView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logcat clearly states that you need to provide the resource id for a textview, where as what you are providing is a linearlayout (My guess since it throws ClassCastException) I believe you main.xml is a linearlayout and not a textview. Instead try `R.id.ringtone`

Answer (score 1):

well friend your problem is you are using r.layout.main for list row.

you have to create a separete listrow layout where you mention only textview
and pass it as a layout
your error is on this line

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindFilesByType.this, R.layout.main,
                Ringtones));
```

create a layout say listrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TexView
.....
/>
```

and change your line

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindFilesByType.this, R.layout.listrow,
                    Ringtones));
```

Comment: ok i got the solution   :-                     this.lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindFilesByType.this, android.R.layout.test_list_item,Ringtones));

Answer (score 0):

You problem is described in these lines:

```
11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
04-27 11:05:08.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(715):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340)
```

It probably means that you are using something as a `LinearLayout`, while it isn't one.
(most of the time you get a ClassCastException you're doing something like
 `foobar = (LinearLayout) someCode();` )